# Drop frame testcase get failed in Qual-E

Tags: cobalt

We are facing the frame drop testcase failure in Playback Rate -> Playback perf on Qual-E. From the test script, we found the FrameDrop (1. FrameDrop) test case and HFR testcase (97. PlaybackPerf.H264.1080p60@2X) uses the same content but the expectation for FrameDrop case is dropped frame count should be more than 2 and for HFR (97. PlaybackPerf.H264.1080p60@2X) case the dropped frame count should be less than or equal to 1. We are not sure how to met the expectation for the both testcases (With frame drop and without frame drop) using same content.

We have also checked the cobalt 19.lts.1.183273 & chrome browser and we are facing the HFR testcase get failed.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not related to Cobalt. Can you please reach out to your YouTube technical account manager for the certification related questions?